# Looking at the class side by side

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to ask an eclipse problem I'm facing recently.

I see that one of the functions of eclipse is that you can see two classes at once side by side. However, when I open like 10 classes, I can no longer drag classes to the other section anymore.

I've tried almost every button on Eclipse Window and yet lost. If you had similar problems, could you please share with me your story?

[image]

Comment: Did you restart your eclipse ide?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What version of eclipse is it ?

Comment: Works fine on my end. We need more details about your eclipse and if you have changed anything, something unusual?

Comment: @AesSedai101 Thank you for the kind mention. I will read it more thoroughly. I was a little too quick and stubborn in asking the question.

Comment: @Dev4World It does work again when I turn off everything and restart eclipse. But I had to do it a little too frequently. If it keeps on happening, I am actually thinking of reinstalling eclipse just in case I made a mistake with its setting.

Comment: @AxelH I've downloaded from the eclipse site in mid-September this year so I'm pretty confident it's the latest version. It seems like the problem is arising when I opened too many classes. I don't understand why it happens to me while it's okay with other classmates. Just in case I've changed one of the settings, I'm thinking of reinstalling eclipse.

Comment: @Zabuza It works fine with you right? My classmates who are learning with me seem to be fine too. I'll try to figure it out the problem. The only setting I think I've changed is the theme color. Is there a way to bring it back to default situation by any chance? Or else I'm thinking of reinstalling eclipse

Comment: What OS, Eclipse Version (what package from the web site ?), plug-in added, ...  If you are the only one to encounter this, you need to be more specific about your system. I suggest you download a new version, and test with a clean install.

Comment: Hi Joon download eclipse neon binary file.You dont need to install when download binary file. Just you can run it. Link -: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64.zip

Comment: @AxelH Ah! Sorry for not being specific. So it was Windows 7 professional K,  eclipse-jee-oxygen-R-win32-x86_64.zip (), and I didn't add any plug-ins. Since it's not likely that eclipse is not functioning properly just to me, I must have made a mistake in the installation process. Thank you for the guidance AxelH! It made me think differently.

Comment: @Dev4World Thank you Dev4World. Let me give it a try right away :)

Comment: Instead of using an outdated version like Neon.3 (like proposed by @Dev4World), update via _Help > Check for Updates_ to Oxygen.1a and after update has finished, try again.

Comment: I already used oxygen. I think neon is stable more than oxygen.

Comment: @Dev4World Neon is no longer maintained. Oxygen.1a is the current version (which is the maintenance release of Oxygen.1 which is the  maintenance release of Oxygen.0). If you want to support open source like Eclipse, use always the current versions and report problems.

Comment: @howleger Thank you howleger.  I really appreciate for taking the time to reply. I was able to learn more about eclipse.

Comment: @Dev4World I will work hard to understand one day what exactly 'stable' means Dev4World. Just a beginner at the moment who learned about a month. I once again appreciate you for taking the time in answering my question.